# error: command '/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc' failed with exit status 1 on Colab

Tags: deep-learning

**I had cloned these repo !git clone https://github.com/lbin/DCNv2.git and try to Build on Google colab but got these error**

Answer (score 1):

**These error occur because DCNv2 require torch version 1.4.0 so simply I had degraded torch version after that try to build again**

`!pip install -U torch==1.4 torchvision==0.5 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch_stable.html`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks，I fixed.
Simply I had degraded torch version after that try to build again：

```
!pip install -U torch==1.4 torchvision==0.5 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch_stable.html
```